# Flipping range of values in array or raster

Tags: raster, array

I have a continuous raster with a range of 0.135 - 0.921 and I want to flip the range or invert it, so the values are min becomes max and max becomes min. I've tried using `np.flip()` but that results in flipping the array instead of the values, so I was thinking about the following workflow:

1. Get unique values and sort them
2. Use `(max + min) - x` to generate flipped values
3. Place original and flipped values into a list and reclass values

I feel like there's an easier way to accomplish this.

```
            old                                 new             
0.23    0.21    0.48    0.55    |   0.82    0.85    0.57    0.51
0.70    0.48    0.96    0.23    |   0.37    0.63    0.09    0.82
0.23    0.23    0.76    0.42    |   0.82    0.82    0.29    0.67
0.91    0.91    0.05    0.68    |   0.14    0.14    1.00    0.50
0.54    0.38    0.53    1.00    |   0.51    0.67    0.52    0.09
0.91    0.54    0.73    0.22    |   0.14    0.52    0.32    0.84
0.17    0.20    0.09    0.76    |   0.96    0.88    0.96    0.29
0.23    0.91    0.91    0.23    |   0.82    0.14    0.14    0.82


old values  | new values ((max+min) - x)
-----------------------------------------
0.05        |            1.00
0.09        |            0.96
0.17        |            0.88
0.2         |            0.85
0.21        |            0.84
0.22        |            0.83
0.23        |            0.82
0.38        |            0.67
0.42        |            0.63
0.48        |            0.57
0.48        |            0.57
0.53        |            0.52
0.54        |            0.51
0.55        |            0.50
0.68        |            0.37
0.7         |            0.35
0.73        |            0.32
0.76        |            0.29
0.76        |            0.29
0.91        |            0.14
0.91        |            0.14
0.96        |            0.09
1           |            0.05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to apply your formula:

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.random(100).reshape((10, 10))  # fake a 10x10 raster

inverted = (np.max(image) - np.min(image)) - image
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm. It threw me off at first because the numbers were off a little but then I realized my source data is in float point e.g. 0.0001 which was causing a slight mismatch.